# Trouble getting LED to turn on

Tags: microcontroller, stm32f4

I've been trying to turn on LED6 on my STM32F407VG Discovery board but for some reason it will not turn on.

My code looks like this:

```
int main(void)
```

{

```
//PD 15

RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIODEN;

GPIOD->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER15_0;

GPIOD->OTYPER &= ~(GPIO_OTYPER_OT_15);

GPIOD->OSPEEDR |= GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR15;

GPIOD->PUPDR &= ~(GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR15);


GPIOD->BSRRH = GPIO_BSRR_BS_15;


return 0;
```

}

I am using Attolic True studio. When i run the debugger the registers all have the correct looking values in them. The only LEDs that light up are LED1 and LED2  - the power indicator.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Look like correct but, as I remember stm32f4xx.h has no **BSRRH** and **BSRRL** registers (at least last versions) register named as **BSRR**. Please try to replace the last row to:

```
GPIOD->ODR |= GPIO_ODR_OD15;
```

If this code will work, this means you were set incorrect value to BSRRH or need use BSRRL register.

Comment: That worked! thank you very much for your help, was bashing my head against the wall for a while! :)